# Rails, ActiveRecord, & Kaminari for pagination

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a **www.messenger.com clone**. A user has many conversations with other users. The conversations have many messages.

The index action sorts the messages in the correct order that I need(most recent on the bottom.) However, it doesn't give me the LAST page initially.

```
### Sorted correct order/direction, but not last page. I need the last page of the pagination to be the 'first' page.
def index
  @conversations = current_user.sorted_conversations.page(params[:page])
  @conversation = @conversations.first
  @messages = @conversations.first.messages.order('created_at ASC').page(params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Just imagine most chat apps scrolling up to retrive older messages. I feel like this isn't a duplicate because other similar questions involve gymnastics and my boss/mentor constantly tells me if I'm doing a lot then I'm probably doing it wrong.

I feel like there's got to be a simpler way to do it via the database query and not using additional helpers. Also I tried solving it with `.reverse` but then ActiveRecord complains

> undefined method total_pages' for #

Comment: why not put the most recent messages on the top?

Comment: I want this app to behave like FB where the most recent messages are at the bottom and scrolling up gives the user older messages.